# How to get list of context words in Gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, fasttext

How to get most frequent context words from pretrained fasttext model?

For example:
For word 'football' and corpus `["I like playing football with my friends"]`

Get list of context words: `['playing', 'with','my','like']`

I try to use 
`model_wiki = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("wiki.ru.vec")
model.most_similar("блок")`

But it's not satisfied for me

Answer (score 0):

The plain model doesn't retain any such co-occurrence statistics from the original corpus. It just has the trained results: vectors per word.

So, the ranked list of `most_similar()` vectors – which isn't exactly words that appeared-together, but strongly correlates to that – is the best you'll get from that file.

Only going back to the original training corpus would give you exactly what you've requested.